# Is it possible for a Book to have multiple ISSN?

Tags: publishing, isbn

It is obvious that a serial may be published in multiple books. Thus a single ISSN could have multiple ISBN releases.

How about the otherway, Is it possible for a book, to be published under multiple Serial? Thus that single ISBN belongs to multiple ISSN.

Cross Reference: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59872/is-it-possible-for-an-book-belongs-to-multiple-serial

Answer (score 1):

A single book/journal/whatever will have a different ISBN for each edition and variation, except for reprints of such, where the reprint will have the same ISBN as the original.

A series of books can (and most probably, will) have separate ISSN for print (the p-ISSN)) version and electronic (the e-ISSN ) version. The series can also be assigned an unique L-ISSN, that is based on the ISSN of the first published version.

Thus, a book, when included as a part of different series (with different ISSN) will have a different ISBN, since it will be published as a separate edition of the book for each series, even if contents will be the same.
Only case I can think of, where the ISBN will be the same, is reprint of the whole series, but then again, most likely the ISSN of the reprint will be the same as original, too.

Sources:

[ISBN Agency](https://www.isbn-international.org/)

[Wikipedia entry on ISSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Serial_Number)